# Updating contents of an iRibbon control from another control's callback

Tags: vba, excel-2010, ribbon

Back in the old days of VBA, we used to be able to directly access controls on a form by name. I'm a little perplexed by how to do this in VBA 2010 (or if it's even possible any longer).

Say I have a ribbon control with a dropdown list called "channelList", and elsewhere on the ribbon I have a textbox called "labelText". Each of these items has a unique callback function - when I type something into labelText, its callback fires, and when I select an item from the channelList listbox, its callback fires with the list item passed as an argument.

Where I'm stumped by is how I would update the labelText textbox contents with 'something' from within the channelList callback.

Is there a way to directly access the textbox control from within the listbox callback, or must I generate some sort of event? What method or function would I use to set the text value for the control? (Do I need to cast the IRibbonControl object to something?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was a combination of an answer and the comments, so here goes:

- Add a "getText" callback subroutine name to the Ribbon XML, specific to the "labelText" editbox.

```
    editBox id="labelText" label="Text:" sizeString="xxxxxxxxxx"
    onChange="TextboxCallback" getText="UpdateTextBoxText"
    screentip="Channel label"
    supertip="Limited to 10 characters. Press Enter once finished typing."
```

- In the combo box callback function, set the desired editbox text to a global and call Ribbon.InvalidateControl with "labelText" as the argument.

```
    MyRibbon.InvalidateControl "labelText"
```

- Implement the editbox callback, passing a handle to the ribbon and another variable ByRef to contain the 'stuff' to be updated. Use the global to update the control's text via the ByRef argument.

```
    Sub UpdateTextBoxText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    Select Case (control.id)       
        Case "labelText"
            returnedVal = LabelText
    End Select
    End Sub
```

I guess this is "progress". labelText.Value = "blah" is *far* too simple.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `Ribbon.Invalidate` method. When you "invalidate" the ribbon you basically reset it, and in that moment you can set the properties of controls on the ribbon based on whatever you can track in that moment. In order to do so, you need to have `Control.GetEnabled`, `GetVisible`, etc., subroutines in your VBA.

You can also invalidate individual controls with `Ribbon.InvalidateControl`.

Here's a link that might help: http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-excel/resetting-controls.html

Comment: Invalidating the control makes sense to me, but I still don't know how to set the new textbox value from the callback function, since the labelText ribbon control doesn't seem to have any methods or exposure to VBA (that I can find, anyhow). What method do I need to call to actually set the text, and where/how is this documented? I've searched the VBA help fruitlessly.

Comment: You won't find this in VBA help. You'll need to search on for Ribbon-related posts. Also, you should use some kind of Ribbon UI editor. I use [Andy Pope's](http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm). When I look at it, I see an EditBox and Label control, no "labelText" control. The events for the ones I see are EditBox.GetText and Label.GetLabel. Note that this stuff is confusing at first. Ideally, I'd get a book that addresses Ribbon customization - maybe Professional Excel Development.

Comment: labelText is the name I assigned my EditBox control. I use the Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office, which is 100% bare bones. I'll take your suggestion on a book and will look at your suggested program. 2010 VBA is such a paradigm shift from 2003-earlier with this Ribbon stuff, it's essentially like a new language. I've gone from fluency to utter illiteracy.

Comment: My ribbon stuff doesn't appear when I load it with the suggested tool - it's as if there's no ribbon defined in the XLS file. I'm really puzzled now.

Comment: Hang in there. You're right, it's a big change, and not as fun,  at least at first. It gets easier though.  Maybe try doing one from scratch?

Comment: @DougGlancy Is using a module-level variable the only way to do this? Since variables can empty in certain situations in Excel, I'm wondering if there's a different way to invalidate a control or ribbon?

Comment: @ARich, sorry I don't have time right now. I'd consider adding a question with your particulars.