# Access 2016: How to show custom ribbon tab when login screen is passed? (with vba)

Tags: vba, ms-access, tabs, ribbon, visible

I created a custom ribbon in the USysRibbons. It contains a guest tab, and other tabs according to employee roles.

```
<customUI onLoad="OnRibbonLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" >
    <ribbon startFromScratch="true" >
        <tabs>
            <tab id="Guest" label="Guest User">
            </tab>
            <tab id="PM" label="Project Manager" getVisible="RibbonGetVisible" tag="PM">
            </tab>
            <tab id="SE" label="System Engineer" getVisible="RibbonGetVisible" tag="SE">
            </tab>
            <tab id="DE" label="Design Engineer" getVisible="RibbonGetVisible" tag="DE">
            </tab>
            </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

The callback "RibbonGetVisible" sets all tabs to visible="false" when the application starts.

```
Public Function RibbonGetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
    Debug.Print "In RibbonGetVisible Function"
    Select Case control.Tag
        Case "PM"
            visible = "false"
        Case "SE"
            visible = "false"
        Case "DE"
            visible = "false"
    End Select
End Function
```

I cannot stop the code with a break point in the callback function but I noticed with Debug.Prints that the callback is triggered before my login screen.

My two questions:

- I call a sub if the user passes the login screen. In this sub, I listed the user's roles and now I want to turn visible corresponding tabs. How should I proceed?
- Later, I will split the database. The USysRibbons is a table, therefore part of the back end, whereas the ribbon is part of the front end. Will it be possible for different users to have only their tabs visible, or do I need to create several ribbons in the USysRibbons? Each user can have zero, one or many roles, each role having one tab. I would prefer to manage only one ribbon to avoid complexity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `visible = "false"` and not `visible = False` ?

Comment: My USysRibbons table is in the frontend. I think you will need different ribbon for each role or combination of roles.

Comment: It works with both "false" of False. I will let visible = False it is more readable.  
If the USysRibbons table will be in the frontend, and each user has a local copy of it, then I think I can have only one ribbon, if I can manage to turn visible allowed tabs after the login screen.

Comment: You will need to use `Ribbon.Invalidate` after login. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004053/updating-contents-of-an-iribbon-control-from-another-controls-callback